# php mode ccm openssl nounce bug

Tags: php, cryptography, aes

Hi i'm trying to encrypt with AES-CCM-256 via php openssl function but it seems that it have a bug when the IV is 12 bytes it result wrong tag , just like how someone explained to me here in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781987/how-to-decrypt-in-php-an-encrypted-text-by-python-using-aes-256-ccm)

is there is any solution or another way that i can encrypt aes-ccm-256 using IV/nonce (12 byte) in PHP

Note: i need to use 12 byte length for IV/nonce , and unfortunately i have to do it with php

Answer (score 1):

I had luck with this using the Openssl library. I wrote a library that wraps some of the encryption and decryption functionality available in Openssl to hopefully make it simpler.

Here's a short example that uses AES-256-CCM to encrypt and decrypt a string using a 12 byte IV:

```
use Encryption\Encryption;

require('../vendor/autoload.php');

$text = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$key  = 'secretkey';

$encryption = Encryption::getEncryptionObject('AES-256-CCM');
$iv = $encryption->generateIv();
$encryptedText = $encryption->encrypt($text, $key, $iv, $tag);
$decryptedText = $encryption->decrypt($encryptedText, $key, $iv, $tag);

printf('Cipher   : %s%s', $encryption->getName(), PHP_EOL);
printf('IV       : %s%s', base64_encode($iv), PHP_EOL);
printf('IV Length: %s%s', strlen($iv), PHP_EOL);
printf('Tag      : %s%s', base64_encode($tag), PHP_EOL);
printf('Encrypted: %s%s', $encryptedText, PHP_EOL);
printf('Decrypted: %s%s', $decryptedText, PHP_EOL);
```

Outputs:

```
Cipher   : AES-256-CCM
IV       : i925n5X6xdrKyImY
IV Length: 12
Tag      : b/fl4BEDAGN5U0P40/GN7g==
Encrypted: zcfFmoRKZNxxwh4z9FGaY63bl4YXYnzSxlLFEE+e9QqsMhoJjpsJ6ALH2ho+ochS
Decrypted: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

If this is good enough for you, the library is called [PHP Simple Encryption](https://github.com/stymiee/php-simple-encryption) and is available as a [composer package](https://packagist.org/packages/stymiee/php-simple-encryption).

Comment: it didn't work when i tried to decrypt a ciphertext  from python that was encrypted using IV 12 byte , but it work with different byte length ,13 for example , looks like it only decrypt what was encrypted by the function itself if i chose 12 byte

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand what you mean. If the IV is not 12 characters long I would expect an error to occur as that is what openssl expects for this cipher. But, if you can provide an example of something encoded with python using this cipher, including the original text, the IV used, and key used, and the tag generated, that would help to reproduce the issue and troubleshoot.

Comment: look at this link and you will find my python code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781987/how-to-decrypt-in-php-an-encrypted-text-by-python-using-aes-256-ccm)

Comment: it give the following error 
`rtrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, bool given` at decryptAeadMode.php(12): 
rtrim(false)

Comment: did you saw my previous question in the link ? any help ? please

Comment: I can't help you with decoding that Python issue as already stated in that question. But the code above will encrypt and decrypt text with AES-256-CCM.

Comment: ok i understand , but unfortunately it can't decode cipher text from SJCL and python it work if both the decrypt and encrypt happens with php openssl function , but SJCL and python can work together in decrypt and encrypt for AES-256-CCM here is an example 
**ciphertext base64** `yR/+6PIO4QI79P+alSFUk0ioRJ866Yzdk9v4bUn2DF2FzrQWB1nCt2QGCg==`, **key** base64 `vX/JWrBukrF6XhXLz6xorBfLjUUfPBywh25xFmgzXME=` ,**IV** base64 `mcWjjNWdWE4gu1mD `, **tag** `6E+QGIHUmKbf/yg40t2Fuw==` , this return "The quick brown fox......" but it didn't work in the code above but it work fine using  SJCL or python

Comment: @AymenDerradji - _PHP Simple Encryption_ uses internally `openssl_encrypt` and `openssl_decrypt` and for AES-CCM a 12 bytes nonce. So this implementation is also affected by the bug. As a result, encryption and decryption are possible within _PHP Simple Encryption_ (just like with `openssl_encrypt` and `openssl_decrypt`), but not in combination with other implementations, be it Python, Java or any implementation that meets the CCM specification.